# On a page refresh, where should we call get token or user details API's when using Nuxt in SSR mode?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, universal

Since in ssr mode middleware executes on server side, how can i call getUserDetails API(requires Bearer token which i stored in localstorage) or any other user permissions related api on page refresh ?

(middleware) auth-admin.js

```
export default async function ({ $auth, redirect, store }) {
  console.log('inside middleware outside process.browser');
  if (process.browser) {
    console.log('inside middleware process.browser', localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'))
    if ($auth.loggedIn && !$auth.user.userId) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')
      try {
        await store.dispatch('login/getUserDetails', token)
      } catch (e) {
        this.$auth.logout()
        redirect('/login')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

component (dashboard.vue)

```
export default {
  middleware: 'auth-admin',(declared middleware)
```

console is not printing inside process.browser block

[image]

Comment: So here, what are your `nuxt.config.js`'s `ssr` and `target` values ? Btw, middleware executes on both sides (server + client) AFAIK.

Comment: if am using localStorage inside middlware , i am getting localStorage not defined error and if i am using inside if(process.browser) on page refresh code inside this process.browser block is not getting executed,

don't know why

Comment: Did not answered to the first part of my comment. For your comment, I do agree on the first part, for the second part: please provide some code for us to debug and see why it is not executed.

Comment: there are no target and ssr values in nuxt.config.js, may be taking default values

Comment: It is process.client and there is no localStorage in server-side.
Cookies can be client or server-side.